# Canonical embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading the second chapter of this [paper](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416) and I need help to understand what exactly this canonical embedding is:

[image]

**Remark:** $C$ is a smooth non-hyperelliptic complete irreducible algebraic curve of genus $g\ge 4$.

Comment: See for example section 16.4 of Vakil's notes (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf), along with chapter 19.  Alternatively see the section of Hartshorne called "The canonical embedding".

Comment: @Adeel thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The comment of Adeel refers to the correct sources, but this sums it up: If $C$ is a curve, the canonical sheaf is the sheaf $\Omega^1_{C/k}$. Global sections of this sheaf are everywhere regular differential forms $C$.

The number of sections of $\Omega^1_{C/k}$ is by definition the genus of the curve. The degree of $\Omega_{C/k}^1$ (as a divisor) is by Riemann-Roch $2g-2$.

Now, if $\omega := \Omega_{C/k}^1$ is very ample (which is the case if the genus is high enough and is the case here), then we get a map $C \to \mathbb P^{g-1}$ given by sending a point $x \in C$ to the point $(\omega_1(x):\omega_2(x):\ldots :\omega_g(x)) \in \mathbb P^{g-1}$ where $\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_g$ is a fixed basis of $\Gamma(C,\omega)$.

Answer (score 2):

When I started reading stuffs for my master thesis I was also puzzled about this.

Hopefully the introduction chapter of my thesis will be insightful for you! There are some drawings and examples which could be useful, especially if you want to get some geometrical intuition about what's going on.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/AndreaBarbon/Algebraic-Brill-Noether-Theory/blob/master/Andrea%20Barbon%20-%20Algebraic%20Brill-Noether%20Theory.pdf?raw=true). Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Very interesting!